# Simplify and rewrite in term of i

Tags: complex-numbers

[The problem click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8RGh.png)

I believe the answer is (b) I tried it in my calculator and it's by far the closest answer from the rest of the other options but it could also be (a) and that's where I need your help guys.

Could it be non above?, Because it sure seems like it in the calculator.

Comment: i got $\frac{40}{3}i$

Comment: Please typeset the equation here, both for convenience and to avoid link rot.

Comment: √-25 . √-64 / √-9

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Notice, we know that $\color{blue}{i^2=-1}$

Now, we have

$$\frac{\sqrt{-25}\cdot \sqrt{-64}}{\sqrt{-9}}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{25i^2}\cdot \sqrt{64i^2}}{\sqrt{9i^2}}$$
$$=\frac{5i\cdot 8i}{3i}$$
$$=\color{red}{\frac{40}{3}i}$$

Comment: could it be non above?

Comment: Yes, you are right